# LAN connection drops when screen turns off

Tags: windows-7, lan, thinkpad

I have a very strange issue with my network connection on my laptop.

My LAN connection disconnects every time my lcd screen light turns off. and when I press a key or move the mouse to turn on the screen the lan connection restarts and gets connected again. but it will be disconnected all the time that the screen is off.

> System: 
>   Lenovo-T500 (
>   Win7 Pro x64 )

I have a PC with the same OS connected to the same network and don't have this problem with my PC it's only happening to my laptop.

this will even happen if I turn my laptop's screen off manually using a function key.

Comment: Is the laptop going to sleep when the screen goes off?

Comment: No. I've turned off all the setting so that it wouldn't go to sleep or hibernate.

Comment: Have you checked the setting that is accessed through the LAN > properties > configure button?

Comment: I disabled that too (after you mentioned it).
but still lan get's disconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally managed to fix it with the latest Intel's network driver for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Let us make sure that the computer doesn’t turn the network adapter off to save power.

a.   Press Windows key + R and type devmgmt.msc in the Run Dialog.

b.  In the Device Manager window, expand Network Adapters.

c.   Right-click on the device and click on Properties.

d.  Click on the Power Management tab and uncheck the option: Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power.

e.  Click on OK to save the settings.

Restart the computer and check if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Check your power settings and make sure your network card will not disconnect to save power. Here is a simple how-to [Windows 7 Power Settings](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/778-power-plan-settings-change.html).

Comment: I checked there are no options enabled to turn of the network card.